# What is the test procedures for a flame arrester?

Tags: safety, fire

A [flame arrester](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UsdId5Oddk) is basically a heat exchanger in front of the tubulure. It conducts the heat of flame to some other place (to the liquid and/or the container especially if the container is built from a metal material), thereby extinguishes the flame before getting into the container.

I built a simple flame arrester with a tea strainer in front of the bottle and dumped some drops of denaturated alcohol into the fire. A controlled experiment demonstrated that the flame arrester works and if there is no flame arrester, an explosion is inevitable.

However, I don't think I should use this approach in a real-life situation because I can't know how much flame the arrester could arrest in a real case.

How can I test a proper flame arrester if it is produced correctly?

Comment: Not something you should be experimenting with... aka a Darwin Award application...

Comment: That was funny :D But, that can't be true. It should be possible to test a flame arrester, at least there should be such a test setup in its production facility.

Comment: You will probably find an *ASTM Test Standard* for flame arrestors, as they are used throughout industry and on things like generators and motorcycle exhaust systems.

Comment: DIN EN ISO 16852 Flame arresters - Performance requirements, test methods and limits for use. I don't have access to this code, you likely will have to purchase it.